# Unable to set Nvidia GPU Fan Speeds

Tags: nvidia, docker, gpu, fan

I am trying to set the Nvidia GPU fan speeds from inside a Ubuntu-based Docker container on a machine with Nvidia RTX 3090. To conserve GPU VRAM, X server is not running.

How can the GPU fan speeds be set to a constant speed, like `90%`?

```
$ sudo nvidia-settings -a "[gpu:0]/GPUFanControlState=1" -a "[fan:0]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=90"

ERROR: The control display is undefined; please run `nvidia-settings --help` for usage information.
```

```
$ sudo nvidia-settings --display :0 -a GPUFanControlState=1 -a GPUTargetFanSpeed=90


ERROR: The current user does not have permission for operation


ERROR: Error assigning value 1 to attribute 'GPUFanControlState' ([gpu:0]) as specified in assignment 'GPUFanControlState=1' (Operation
       not supported).


ERROR: The current user does not have permission for operation


ERROR: Error assigning value 1 to attribute 'GPUFanControlState' ([gpu:1]) as specified in assignment 'GPUFanControlState=1' (Operation
       not supported).


ERROR: The current user does not have permission for operation


ERROR: Error assigning value 1 to attribute 'GPUFanControlState' ([gpu:2]) as specified in assignment 'GPUFanControlState=1' (Operation
       not supported).


ERROR: The current user does not have permission for operation


ERROR: Error assigning value 1 to attribute 'GPUFanControlState' ([gpu:3]) as specified in assignment 'GPUFanControlState=1' (Operation
       not supported).


ERROR: The current user does not have permission for operation


ERROR: Error assigning value 1 to attribute 'GPUFanControlState' ([gpu:4]) as specified in assignment 'GPUFanControlState=1' (Operation
       not supported).


ERROR: The current user does not have permission for operation


ERROR: Error assigning value 1 to attribute 'GPUFanControlState' ([gpu:5]) as specified in assignment 'GPUFanControlState=1' (Operation
       not supported).


ERROR: The current user does not have permission for operation


ERROR: Error assigning value 1 to attribute 'GPUFanControlState' ([gpu:6]) as specified in assignment 'GPUFanControlState=1' (Operation
       not supported).


ERROR: The current user does not have permission for operation


ERROR: Error assigning value 1 to attribute 'GPUFanControlState' ([gpu:7]) as specified in assignment 'GPUFanControlState=1' (Operation
       not supported).



ERROR: The current user does not have permission for operation


ERROR: Error assigning value 90 to attribute 'GPUTargetFanSpeed' ([fan:0]) as specified in assignment 'GPUTargetFanSpeed=90' (Operation
       not supported).


ERROR: The current user does not have permission for operation


ERROR: Error assigning value 90 to attribute 'GPUTargetFanSpeed' ([fan:1]) as specified in assignment 'GPUTargetFanSpeed=90' (Operation
       not supported).


ERROR: The current user does not have permission for operation


ERROR: Error assigning value 90 to attribute 'GPUTargetFanSpeed' ([fan:2]) as specified in assignment 'GPUTargetFanSpeed=90' (Operation
       not supported).


ERROR: The current user does not have permission for operation


ERROR: Error assigning value 90 to attribute 'GPUTargetFanSpeed' ([fan:3]) as specified in assignment 'GPUTargetFanSpeed=90' (Operation
       not supported).


ERROR: The current user does not have permission for operation


ERROR: Error assigning value 90 to attribute 'GPUTargetFanSpeed' ([fan:4]) as specified in assignment 'GPUTargetFanSpeed=90' (Operation
       not supported).


ERROR: The current user does not have permission for operation


ERROR: Error assigning value 90 to attribute 'GPUTargetFanSpeed' ([fan:5]) as specified in assignment 'GPUTargetFanSpeed=90' (Operation
       not supported).


ERROR: The current user does not have permission for operation


ERROR: Error assigning value 90 to attribute 'GPUTargetFanSpeed' ([fan:6]) as specified in assignment 'GPUTargetFanSpeed=90' (Operation
       not supported).


ERROR: The current user does not have permission for operation


ERROR: Error assigning value 90 to attribute 'GPUTargetFanSpeed' ([fan:7]) as specified in assignment 'GPUTargetFanSpeed=90' (Operation
       not supported).
```

Using `NVIDIA-SMI 535.86.05`.